# bulk collect and forall

Tags: oracle, plsql

With cursor, bulk collect and forall, I'm trying to understand when to use

```
 1 .. count
```

and when to use

```
first .. last
```

Can anyone explain with an examples of forall insert, forall update and forall deletes, please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PL/SQL documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99965):

> For a varray that is not empty, FIRST always returns 1. For every
>   varray, LAST always equals COUNT.

Things are different for associative arrays, where FIRST and LAST reference the minimum and maximum values of the INDEX BY index.

Things are also different with nested tables. Again the documentation says:

> For a nested table, COUNT equals LAST unless you delete elements from
>   the middle of the nested table, in which case COUNT is smaller than
>   LAST

Now you ask about FORALL statements. We can use any type of collection in the bounds clause (although only associative arrays which are `index by pls_integer`). The restriction is that the lower and upper bounds of the clause must define a [series of consecutive valid numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321).

So, if your collection is a nested table or varray use `1 .. whatever.count()`. If your collection is an associative array with an index which doesn't start with 1 but is still consecutive use `whatever.first() .. whatever.last()`. Otherwise use `indices of` or `values of`.